# Trying to access the 'Files' section of the admin console on a simple deployed SilverStripe website presents an error

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I’ve recently picked up SilverStripe (v4.5) for a relatively small-scale website project, and haven’t had any issues with the system on my local development environment (XAMPP, with PHP 7.4.7, Apache v2.4.43, 10.4.13-MariaDB). However when the website is deployed, I am unable to access the ‘Files’ section of the admin console, with the error message:

> Cannot query field “version” on type “File”. Did you mean “extension”?

I am still able to upload files (indirectly) through other elements in the CMS (UploadFields on pages / objects, for instance) and these uploaded files do appear in the database.

Initially we were running the site on nginx, but have since switched to apache2, which did not solve the problem.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Just checking, did you run `dev/build` and flush your cache (buy adding `?flush` to the query string)?

Comment: Yes, I've been able to successfully work on other parts of this website for a few weeks without any issue. Have tried running dev/build and flushing cache multiple times during that period, and while attempting to trace this error, but to no end.

Comment: It feels like a case sensitivity issue to me. Are there places in your project code where you're referring to `version` on a File? Maybe in GraphQL?

Comment: I don't believe so. The project code for this website is very simple, the only places where I am referring to file in my own code are in a simple DataObject.

Comment: Please double check that you ran dev/build successfully. Then, please update your post and show the relevant dataobjects that interact with files. Also, do you have any DataExtension that are attached to File? Did you install any other modules that might have DataExtensions?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your helpful suggestions on this question. In the meantime I have been able to solve the problem, however I'm still unsure what the root cause of the issue was.

I started from scratch, created a new EC2 instance, installed all the SS dependencies from scratch and created a new project, then migrated my SS content into that project. In that new project, this issue had been resolved, as such I'm able to continue with my development.

My best guess would be some sort of version mismatch between the original SilverStripe project files and the dependencies installed on the original EC2 instance. I apologise for not being able to provide more clarity than that.